# Appending a list of dictionaries within a file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to take a dictionary popped from a list and append it to another list and save it as a new file.

If the file is blank I can create a new list of dictionaries and save the file, but if there is an existing list of dictionaries dont know how to check the file for a list (it will either be blank or a list of dicts), and if there is, append the file.  I can't just append the file because its a list of dictionaries and the trailing `]` would break the list.

My question is how do you check the file if it already contains a list and if it does, how do you append it?  (ie do you have to loop through the exiting list in the file, therefore creating a new list, and append that list with the pop and saving it?... or is there a better way?)

```
import json
import os

def main():

  with open('file1.json', 'r') as fin:
    user_list = json.load(fin)
    temp = user_list.pop(0)

  open_if_not_exists("processed.json")
  
  
  with open('processed.json', 'w') as processed_file:  
    my_list = []
    try:
      data = json.load(processed_file)
      for i in data:
        my_list.append(i)
      my_list.append(temp)
    except (IOError):
      my_list.append(temp)
    
    json.dump(my_list, processed_file)
      
      
  with open('file1.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(user_list, fout)
    
def open_if_not_exists(filename):
  try:
      fd = os.open(filename, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_WRONLY)
  except OSError as e:
      if e.errno == 17:
          return None
      else:
          raise
  else:
      return os.fdopen(fd, 'w')
      
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample data

> [{"id": 1234, "screen_name": "UserName"}, {"id": 5678, "screen_name":
> "Bobo2022"}, {"id": 9101, "screen_name": "ReallyDude"}, {"id": 1213,
> "screen_name": "SMH"}, {"id": 1415, "screen_name": "IAskQuestions"}]

Comment: Please give example data as per this advice; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatBailie In comments you can just write `[mre]` and it expands to *[mre]*. And there are more shorthands listed under [comment formatting help](/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title, and please make a [mre] including some example inputs and desired outputs. It's not clear what you mean by "or data" -- like, would it be valid JSON, or any arbitrary data? And how do you want to handle it exactly? FWIW, it's probably not important that the lists contain dicts; any data would suffice for the sake of example.

Comment: @matBailie Sample data provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick modification to your code...

- It still naively assumes that if a file opens, it contains a valid json array

```
import json
import os

def main():

  processed_list = []

  new_list = []
  new_dict = {}

  with open('file1.json', 'r') as fin:
    new_list = json.load(fin)
    new_dict = new_list.pop(0)

  try:
    with open('processed.json', 'r') as processed_file:  
      processed_list = json.load(processed_file)
  except FileNotFoundError:
    processed_list = [ new_dict ]
  else:
    processed_list.append(new_dict)

  with open('processed.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(processed_list, fout)

  with open('file1.json', 'w') as fout:
    json.dump(new_list, fout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```